# How to replace with ctrl+h in vim

Tags: search, vim, replace, escaping, mapping

I would like to map **<c-h>** to do an easy "replace" in the active buffer

For now I have something like this:

```
" <c-h> Replacement
noremap   <c-h>     :%s/<c-R><c-W>//g<left><left>
inoremap  <c-h>     <esc>:%s/<c-R><c-W>//g<left><left>
vnoremap  <c-h>     gv:%s/<c-R><c-W>//g<left><left>
```

The problems are:

1. The selection is not properly escaped
2. For the visual mode I do not paste the selection, juste the word below the cursor

Is there anyway to do something like:

```
inoremap  <c-h>     <esc>:%s/\=escapechars(<c-R><c-W>)}//g<left><left>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this function:

```
function! GetVisualSelection()
  let old_reg = @v
  normal! gv"vy
  let raw_search = @v
  let @v = old_reg
  return substitute(escape(raw_search, '\/.*$^~[]'), "\n", '\\n', "g")
endfunction
```

which you could use like this:

```
xnoremap <c-h> :<C-u>%s/<C-r>=GetVisualSelection()<CR>//g<left><left>
```

The "escaping" part could be extracted into its own function:

```
function! Escape(stuff)
  return substitute(escape(a:stuff, '\/.*$^~[]'), "\n", '\\n', "g")
endfunction
```

which you could use like this:

```
nnoremap <c-h> :<C-u>%s/<C-r>=Escape(expand('<cword>'))<CR>//g<left><left>
inoremap <c-h> <esc>:%s/<C-r>=Escape(expand('<cword>'))<CR>//g<left><left>
```

Comment: It is almost perfect. I didn't know I can call any functions with the equal symbol and the `<cWORD>` is interesting too However, I think it doesn't really match "a single word" like `yiw`.

Comment: `<cword>` has the same meaning as `iw`: it covers a `word`. `<cWORD>` has the same meaning as `iW`: it covers a `WORD`. You can use one or the other, as you see fit. I'll edit my answer to use `<cword>` anyway: it matches your question better.